# Man page in C application

Tags: c, command-line, manpage

I'm currently working on a little project to test my knowledge in writing C applications.
I try to create a man page which shall open, once `app --help` is typed. How do I change the path, so when I send my work to friends they can also run `app --help` and the man page will open.

Is there any possibility to run a command from a C file like:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "--help") {
   run_in_command_line("man ./app.8");
}
```

Or are there other, better, ways to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`run_in_command_line` may be a call to `system()`, but this will work only if run into a terminal.

Launching `man ./app.8` from your executable is definitely a bad idea, because it would require that the run would be made in the right directory. Such a constraint is considered as bad. Prefer:

- an installation procedure that will install the executable and the man,
- use `system("man app")` in the code, or preferably a help command that gives basic informations and then suggests to read the man for complete information.